# How to install compatible versions of React and Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've attempted to install both React and Material UI as follows:

1. Installed React with `npm install -g create-react-app`
2. Created a project with `npx create-react-app my-app`
3. CD'd into my-app
4. Installed Material Ui with `npm install @mui/material @mui/icons-material`

However, I get notices such as

```
6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

SO I run this command and then generated more vulnerabilities.

```
86 vulnerabilities (14 low, 21 moderate, 43 high, 8 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix
```

Running `npm audit fix` simply takes me back to the 6 vulnerabilities issue, so I'm stuck in a loop.

As I understand it, some version of React and some version of Material UI are compatible with each other, but not the most recent version of each.

So what I'd like to know is- what command can I run such that I install both compatibly?

Comment: These are warnings. The versions you have are compatible, there’s no problem here

Comment: I like to reference this blog by Dan Abramov at times likes this: https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/